# Хранение Emoji с Инстаграм в таблице mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, utf-8

Добрый день!
Скопирован текст с инстаграм, включающий Emoji:

> 123 22

Как его хранить в таблице mysql? Таблица в кодировке **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**, но текст сохраняется со знаками вопросов.

Comment: Соединение с базой должно быть не `utf8`, а `utf8mb4`.

Comment: спасибо, работает!