# Бажные символы MySQL с UTF - обрезка полей, замена на вопросы

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8

Оказывается есть символы, которые SQL не хочет записывать себе в поля в любых utf-кодировках. К примеру пытались записать формулу:

`0 – 1 =`

В кодировках:

```
utf8_general_ci
utf8_unicode_ci
utf16_general_ci
utf32_general_ci
utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Если поле таблицы в utf8 - текст обрывается на первом "бажном" символе, например . В utf16, utf32 - "бажные" символы заменяются на вопросы. При чем эти символы понимаются и в HTML и в PHP. Версия MySQL - 5.6.17, записывать пробовал через php pdo драйвер, и через MySQL Workbench - результат один.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за такая специфичная группа символов(может быть будет ссылка на список)? И как с этим бороться, может быть стоит обновить версию СУБД, или же есть способ хранить текст с этими символами без самопального перекодирования?

Comment: Гляньте сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643217/%d0%a5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-emoji-%d1%81-%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-mysql#comment914414_643217

Comment: @Visman `Соединение с базой должно быть не utf8, а utf8mb4` Спасибо, помогло! Но откуда такие костыли всплывают, неужто utf8 в sql неполноценный?

Comment: в mysql - да, неполноценный utf8, умеет только 3 из 4 байт юникода. Нормальный utf8 завезли позже и назвали utf8mb4.

Comment: Дополню: только начиная с MySQL 5.5.3 поддерживается 4 байта. И только при указание соединения и кодировки таблиц, полей как utf8mb4.

Comment: @Visman пробовали при чём ставить utf8mb4 - воркбенч всё равно отказывался записывать эти символы.. А из PHP и не догадаешься соединение подправить, наплодили короче они неясностей.